# Mapping URL in Maximo Anywhere

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I'm looking to deploy mapping functionality in the Work Execution app within the Maximo Anywhere framework. The issue I'm having is the app throws an error when I attempt to go into the "Map of Work Orders" screen. The error that displays on the screen is

> "Unable to show map. It is possible that the value for the providerURL property is invalid. Contact your administrator."

When I look into the logging data I get a bunch of lines about OpenLayersMap.js - stating that the providerURL is wrong.

In the app.xml for the WorkExecution app we have this configured in the Map tag (line 3320 in our config)

```
        <map adjustToTop="true" androidLocalMapUrl="file://mnt/sdcard/basemaps/Manhattan.tpk" id="WorkExecution.MapView_esri_true" iosLocalMapUrl="Manhattan.tpk" iosMapAccessMethod="useDocumentsFolder" layoutInsertAt="map" provider="esri" workOfflineResource="workOrder" providerUrl="http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"/>
```

Additionally, we've enabled maps in the app-feature.properties file by setting map.enabled=true

Does anyone have online maps working in a test environment on 7.5.2 in the work execution app? If so, mind sharing their config if it hits a public server, or point out what's wrong with ours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message inform you that the value for `providerUrl` is invalid or that this connection to the server could not be achieved. I checked here and it seems that this value is correct.

Are you using the adminmode? Because internally, the value for `providerUrl` from `app.xml` can be replaced by the value of `providerUrl` from the server via adminmode (maximo). To check if you are using it, take a look at your `worklight.properties` file and if the property for `si.adminmode` is `true`, you need to confirm if the value put on maximo to `providerUrl` is a valid one.

Comment: We do have the admin mode enabled within the worklight.properties file. The providerUrl shown in the administrative console is incorrect, but it doesn't look like I can modify it. I'll work to get those permissions and then modify that variable, rebuild, and report back the results.

Comment: Still not showing the mapping. I've reached out to IBM, and will report back what they say.

Comment: Just got this back from IBM :  It appears our KC is not being specific enough on the providerURL value. Please try setting it to the following and test again:

http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}

Comment: As you are using the admin mode, remember that the value from server will replace the value get from app.xml. So, make sure that the value on server is correct. You can change this value for each application that you are using. Remember to save your changes on maximo and re-log on app to get the new values. About the value of providerUrl, the value that you said that is on your app.xml seems good, I mean: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}, so use it on providerUrl from server.